# Why Selenium Grid need Host name or Ip address of the machine

Tags: selenium, automation

If I have 10 similar machine (Browser, OS) to execute a test suite in selenium grid, why do ineed host name or Ip address of the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium hub needs to pass the commands to the RC which is running in other machines as http commands. You would obviously need the IP address or Name of the machine for hub to identify the machine. The below link would provide more details

http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/how_it_works.html